# CSS responsive cards

Tags: html, css, angular

Let's say I have 100 cards as this one:

```
<div class = "card">CARD</div> // this line is repeated 100 times

.card {
  background-color: blue;
  float: left;
  width: 150px;
  height: 75px;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

In this case the layout is responsive. You can see the example here : https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_float_elements

As you see, when you resize the page, more and more cards are moving to next line, until a new line of cards appear.

I would like to add an index beside each line, dinamically displaying the number of cards in each row.
Is this possible with pure html-css? If so, how?

Comment: Is this possible with pure html-css > No you have to use Javascript if you want count occurences

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I solved it using html and css only.
Please resize the page to see the effect.

```css
.underlay {
  z-index: 0;
  margin-right: 40px;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: darkgray;
  top: 0px;
  margin-left: 40px;
}


.underlayBox {
  float: left;
  margin: 2px;
  background-color: white;
  height: 30px;
  width: 60px;
}


.overlayBox {
  float: left;
  margin: 2px;
  background-color: floralwhite;
  height: 30px;
  width: 60px;
}
```

```html
<div class="underlay"><div class="underlayBox">1</div><div class="underlayBox">2</div><div class="underlayBox">3</div><div class="underlayBox">4</div><div class="underlayBox">5</div><div class="underlayBox">6</div></div>')<div class="overlay"><div class="overlayBox">A1</div><div class="overlayBox">A2</div><div class="overlayBox">A3</div><div class="overlayBox">A4</div><div class="overlayBox">A5</div><div class="overlayBox">A6</div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this using CSS counters:

```css
.wrapper {
  counter-reset: line-number 0;
}

.floating-box {
  float: left;
  width: 150px;
  height: 75px;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 3px solid #73AD21;
  counter-increment: line-number 1
}

.floating-box:before {
  content: counter(line-number) ": ";
}
```

```html
<h2>Floating boxes</h2>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="floating-box">Floating box</div>
  <div class="floating-box">Floating box</div>
  <div class="floating-box">Floating box</div>
  <div class="floating-box">Floating box</div>
  <div class="floating-box">Floating box</div>
  <div class="floating-box">Floating box</div>
  <div class="floating-box">Floating box</div>
  <div class="floating-box">Floating box</div>
</div>
```

Comment: While this will accurately count the number of `.floating-box` elements, it won't count the number of items per row (which is what the question was asking for).

Comment: yes, and actually the best for me would be to display only the index of the first box of each line.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use % units relative to the parent element:

So to have 4 boxes in a row:

```
.floating-box {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  height: 75px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 3px solid #73AD21;
}
```

As you see I need to add the [box-sizing](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_box-sizing.asp) property and remove the margin;

To reach the same result you need to add an extra tag:

```
.floating-box {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
}
.floating-box-border {
  height: 75px;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 3px solid #73AD21;
  box-model
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="floating-box">
    <div class="floating-box-border">
        Floating box
    </div>
</div>
```

I suggest you to take a look to some css framework like Bootstrap that as a [advanced Grid system](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/grid/).